# Do Updates from "Windows Server 2016 and Later Servicing Drivers" Apply to 1607

Tags: windows-server-2016, wsus, windows-update

All of my Windows Server 2016 instances are on Version 1607 . Will anything from the WSUS Products channel `Windows Server 2016 and Later Servicing Drivers` apply to these v1607 servers?

[image: wsus prodcuts channel windows server 2016 and later servicing drivers]

It's late, but I haven't been able to make sense of with my own research. I'm guessing it's intended for 1709 and 1803, etc...

I ask because I have this policy for Domain Controllers, and noticed that they report having 100% of updates while being on `OS Build 14393.3274`.

My public facing Windows Server 2016 Version 1607 Servers use Microsoft for updates, and are on `OS Build 14393.3300`.

Comment: Build 14393.3300 is KB4519979.  My WSUS server has all products and classifications enabled, and it has not received this update, so I believe it has not been released via WSUS.  That happens sometimes.  I shouldn't worry; the November cumulative update will bring everything back into line again.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I was having trouble understanding the answer posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, the "Windows Server 2016 and Later Servicing Drivers" product category does contain updates that might be applicable to your servers, but they are all device drivers, so they will not affect the build number.

You can look up an arbitrary build number for Windows Server 2016 [by looking at the list of builds shown in KB4000825](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4000825/windows-10-windows-server-2016-update-history), or it is often easier to just Google the build number.

In this case, the particular Windows build you are interested in was released as [KB4519979](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4519979), on October 15.  I've checked my WSUS server (which has all products and classifications enabled) and this update is not present, nor was any other Windows 2016 update released on or near that date.  So it appears that it simply hasn't been released via WSUS.

Occasionally non-security updates do get left out of WSUS, for reasons that are unclear.  Don't worry about it; when the November updates are released they should bring your DCs back in line with your other servers.

Comment: Great, I was wondering if I'd been missing out on an entire series of updates. Good to know I don't need to enable that product line!

Answer (score 0):

It is the Servicing Stack Update (SSU). The SSU does not change the build major/minor version.

What is a servicing stack update?

Servicing stack updates provide fixes to the servicing stack, the component that installs Windows updates. Additionally, it contains the "component-based servicing stack" (CBS), which is a key underlying component for several elements of Windows deployment, such as DISM, SFC, changing Windows features or roles, and repairing components. The CBS is a small component that typically does not have updates released every month.

Why should servicing stack updates be installed and kept up to date?

Servicing stack updates improve the reliability of the update process to mitigate potential issues while installing the latest quality updates and feature updates. If you don't install the latest servicing stack update, there's a risk that your device can't be updated with the latest Microsoft security fixes.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/servicing-stack-updates#why-should-servicing-stack-updates-be-installed-and-kept-up-to-date

Comment: I've just checked on my WSUS server, and the product category "Windows Server 2016 and Later Servicing Drivers" does not contain any SSU updates.  Instead, it contains a small collection of device drivers - mostly Intel, a handful of VMware, and a few other oddities.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: My bad, thanks for pointing that out.